# Auto Splitting full video using MP4Box

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

Is there any method to achieve auto-splitting of whole video into equal chunks using MP4Box in Ubuntu as we get same using FFMPEG by specifying segments as following

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 8 -f segment output%03d.mp4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two similar arguments for MP4Box.

You can use `wc -c /path/to/file` or `stat -c %s /path/to/file` to get the filesize of a specific file.

The `-split` argument of `MP4Box` allows you to split a file in specific segments.

`-split time_in_seconds`
splits in files of desired maximum duration.

`-splits size_in_kilobytes`
splits in files of desired maximum size.

So to split the file into 15 minute fragments the command is `MP4Box -split 900 filename.mp4`

So, if you always want a video to be split in 5 equal parts in terms of filesize

First, get the filesize using either `wc` or `stat` as stated above, then divide that size by 5, and use `MP4Box -splits filesize path/to/file`

But if you would like to split the video in a certain amount of time:

Use `ffprobe -i some_video -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"` to get the video duration in seconds,

Divide the total length by how many seconds each segment has to take, and voila! Use `MP4Box -split amountOfSeconds path/to/file`

Comment: No problem, and welcome to Stackoverflow! Remember to set a question as the answer by clicking the [tick under the reputation](http://i.imgur.com/6g3LPhm.png).